# Number of closed walks on a regular graph

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, random-walk, trees

In his 1981 work, McKay demonstrates that the eigenvalue distribution of large regular graphs follow the law presented in his [paper](https://pdf.sciencedirectassets.com/271586/1-s2.0-S0024379500X01334/1-s2.0-0024379581901506/main.pdf?X-Amz-Security-Token=AgoJb3JpZ2luX2VjEFUaCXVzLWVhc3QtMSJHMEUCIQCM4mikYyPX0Tjr6exNHHGE1YfcjHdeORlxc2Dwv8y8ygIgPuqP4XWhubJ3dmMF%2BAXqRvHOUlEZQUenZR%2BFqQDLmLAq2gMIThACGgwwNTkwMDM1NDY4NjUiDM2kiMLoo5BKOmoEHyq3AyC7xFwztYFl%2FWDPzTxQ6ckGSnMvI9X726MxOaUr87NGwalqhPrAoMAjWU4Z9ckf0q1NN8vCpei7SOX6OlMEsHvr%2FnemUiTo9gst0Dh1cRAMnPugiYQeLusyce0mgO1lcLQ1E0JQ9ZP8QIR0wlJF39Yp08NB0HqY5i5Bb5pG5W%2B4ydHYY%2BKlq7EcIYwWcpVFBcQROCefrnoEFwo185TBvhvrgBmtHHVTHIxpWK76g8rtOBNj4iT18%2FBE1sNZthQLH0xzR%2FEeSU121ZE6INoM71tGTk4MTOuG3yFR3J%2FUKtmrBHnjOtTcmoHfxbyutadY%2BbGim0sknfstFQtFh7PMgsSTqwOGynjCIQaLGGyP802MGzvHqpa5sLDJZzAMci%2B1pAKWvMKX7D22w9ScfC5wl5R5xOGL%2BO26lfHBRs92p7Q9zXf0i8whV33VQ30KqXTsnUgFSOLRL3025DRBciA2YFWHpjo%2BVbrJ2LfqqX%2BJGJBT%2FqplyBSqImT8NO%2FtASEK2euqPoJQTT76P7Zh600sa7cHfMuzXmmhptbE8GnSUFOxxueTp4Rtgb8j0pfhz%2Bxwrv89um7777wwveSY7QU6tAGWpS66tNUrP6I%2B1CTf2D1w9kZjeFLQ5lrToTcGkN5g4Iu7NW%2BRb%2F4gO10BHqdJ3ZZCN0gv9wtCVGFfXjrYOXcWoXpyrqmHzhJhpjRkM7KVidPcIiJiKP4ez6JA3NyyMPm%2FC78rmQN3FIDDLv9O9EEMK%2FWa4ixhadcfO1C6ibAHtujKFc6G%2B3NdsQgLr8o3XIFBAff4FNAa1rNX7fAfVYSWszPn%2BG%2BJnfMqaSAKnu%2FDpFRV8SU%3D&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Date=20191015T215157Z&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Expires=300&X-Amz-Credential=ASIAQ3PHCVTYZHOUPHUV%2F20191015%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Signature=2795f0fe4cd68543e69cc6846e84ae41d8c068ae4a814e12490de8a9b34a0884&hash=ac28a0d6f1cffd9b7ecd30019c87b9eff68308e834a1defd6aefea88855bce91&host=68042c943591013ac2b2430a89b270f6af2c76d8dfd086a07176afe7c76c2c61&pii=0024379581901506&tid=spdf-22e50f56-5ea8-4077-960b-e740fb575a02&sid=678e31921eb63341b539cde10cdda1ad063dgxrqb&type=client) and which nowadays goes by his name.

At page 205 (the third page from the start of his paper) he counts the closed walks of $r$ steps on a regular graph starting by a point $\nu_0$, with the constraint that locally at $\nu_0$ (precisely in a ray of at least $\frac{r}{2}$) the graph is acyclic. This condition permit to map the problem to the study of the number of possible sequences $\pmb{\delta}=\delta_0\dots\delta_r$ (where is it is found that the walk could have only even steps, $r=2s$) where each $\delta_i$ is the distance of the vertex $\nu_i$ at the $i-$th step of the walk from the node $\nu_0$, (obviously $\delta_0=\delta_r=0, |\delta_{i+1}-\delta_{i}|=1$ and $\delta_i\geq0$). It turns out that the number of the sequences $\delta_1\dots\delta_r$ ($\delta_0$ is $0$ by definition and could be omitted in the study) with the given properties and $k$ element equal to $0$ (the walk returns $k$ times to $\nu_0$ after it started) is $$\binom{2s-k}{s}\cdot\frac{k}{2s-k}$$
The point is that I cannot derive this formula using combinatorics. I found that it could be related to Catalan numbers and Dyck words, but I cannot see how to impose the right constraints which rule out the unwanted path (the paper cite a reference for this result, but is a standard prob&stat book with a chapter on combinatorics, so I guess I am missing some point).